# Jest in Node.js. How to test a function that executes shell commands

Tags: node.js, bash, jestjs

I have not been able to test this function with Jest, I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
/**
 * @function now
 * @description When a Bash script is executed, it instantly displays the responses that appear on the screen.
 * @param {string} script Bash script
 * @example now('echo "Hello World!"')
 */
function now(script) {
  let execute = exec(script)
  execute.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    if (data.charAt(data.length - 1) === '\n') {
      console.log(data.toString().slice(0, -1))
    } else {
      console.log(data.toString())
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `exec` executes asynchronously, you'll need to change the `now` function a bit in order to test it. As it's written, you don't have a way for the caller to know when `now` is finished. The simplest ways to change this are:

1. Make it return a Promise that resolves when it's done
2. Make it take a callback that is called when it's done

### Promise

```
function now(script) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let execute = exec(script)
    execute.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      if (data.charAt(data.length - 1) === '\n') {
        console.log(data.toString().slice(0, -1))
      } else {
        console.log(data.toString())
      }
    })

    // Resolve the Promise when the shell exits
    execute.on('exit', resolve);
    // Error handling omitted for brevity, you can call reject() on failure
  });
}
```

Here's the test. There are various ways to check that `console.log` is called. This one uses a spy but you could also inject a `log` function and default it to `console.log`.

```js
it('logs from shell command', async () => {
  jest.spyOn(console, "log");
  await greet('echo "foo"');
  expect(console.log).toBeCalledWith('foo');
});
```

### Callback

```
function now(script, callback) {
  let execute = exec(script)
  execute.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    if (data.charAt(data.length - 1) === '\n') {
      console.log(data.toString().slice(0, -1))
    } else {
      console.log(data.toString())
    }
  })

  // Resolve the Promise when the shell exits
  execute.on('exit', callback);
  // Error handling omitted for brevity, you can pass an error to the callback on failure
}
```

The `expect` needs to be in the callback so the test waits until the shell has exited. Note that you need to call `done` for the test to finish. Promises are generally more ergonomic, but callbacks have their uses as well so I included them both.

```js
it('logs from shell command', (done) => {
  jest.spyOn(console, "log");
  greet('echo "foo"', () => {
    expect(console.log).toBeCalledWith('foo');
    done()
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @helloitsjoe . I will calmly look at the answer to try to understand. Will it happen just as well if I call multiple commands or one with multiple response lines? like `sudo apt update;`

Comment: Yes, it will log whatever is sent to the shell’s `stdout` until the process exits

Answer (score 0):

Using information from @helloitsjoe I got what I was looking for.

Modify the promise so that it correctly displays the messages on the screen.

```js
 function now(script) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let execute = exec(script)
    execute.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(data.toString().slice(0, -1))
      process.stdout.cursorTo(0)
    })

    execute.on('exit', resolve);
  })
}
```

I use the test with the promise of @helloitsjoe, for it to work I need to install `npm i -D regenerator-runtime` and import it with `import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'`.

Thank you very much @helloitsjoe.